# A way to keep track of lives on scene load

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

is there a way to keep track of how many lives left have the player?

I have a gameobject, it have a script attached to it, the player interacts with the gameobject. Inside the script I have a method called Check(). Using a event trigger (pointer click) I call that method to check if the player lose a life or wins a point. The gameobject is set up using the Start() method on the script attached to it.

If the player lose a life then I should do something like

`lives --;`

So if the initial value was 3, now he will have 2 lives left. Then I need to reload the same scene, and here is where my problem begins...

If I set the amount of lives on the Start() method, when the scene reloads the player will have 3 lives again and of course, that should not happen because the player just lost one life before the scene reload.

I could create an empty gameobject and attach a script to it (let's call it TempScript) with a variable called livesLeft to store there the amount of lives left, and then use the Awake() method and the known

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(This);
```

When the scene reloads the variable livesLeft will not change, so if the player had two lives at reload, after the reload he still will have two lives. The problem using this solution is, how do I set up the initial amount of lives then???

Load scene 1st time -> livesLeft = 3 -> load gameobject -> player interact with gameobject -> Check() is called -> player lose life -> livesLeft = livesLeft - 1 -> reload scene -> livesLeft = 2 -> ...

I'm sorry, maybe this is a very simple question, but I can't see a solution...

Yes, I know about singletons, but I really don't want to use them unless there is no other choice.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use a singleton .
Here is some example code;

```
public class DataHolder : MonoBehaviour
{
public int someData;
public static DataHolder holder; 

void Awake()
{
if (holder == null)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            holder = this;

        }
        else if (holder != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I like singletons to make "managers" like this one you seems to need. You can also check http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton for a thread safe generic singleton to easily extends and make cohesive managers as you need. So I tend to upvote for @Uri's anwer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) class to store data.

It basically stores whatever data you throw at it between sessions.

Example

```
public class Player : Monobehaviour {

    public int lives = 3;

    void Start () {
        //Get the number of lives stored from previous sessions
        //If the key doesn't exist, a value of 0 is returned
        lives = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("lives", 0);
        if(lives == 0)
            lives = 3;
    }


    void Check () {
        //Do your stuff here


        //Reduce lives
        lives--;

        //Save in PlayerPrefs, and COMMIT using PlayerPrefs.Save()
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("lives", lives);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();

        //Reload level
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevelName);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class life : MonoBehaviour {
    int lifes;

    void Awake(){
        lifes = 3;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
    }

    public void looseLife(){
        if (lifes != 0)
            lifes--;
        Debug.Log (lifes);
    }

}
```

This way, whenever scene loads your life count will be preserved. another way is to say your data in playerprefs when exit the scene and call it on load.

Answer (score 0):

basically I would have a gameobject known as gameVariables

inside of that I would have something simple as

```
public class gameVariables: MonoBehaviour
{
public int Lives;
public bool Creation = false;

void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
}

void Start()
{
    if(Creation)
    {
        Lives = 3;
    }
}

public void Updatelives(int value)
{
     Lives += value; //value can be -1 or what not, al
}
}
```

Now on the scene you create this gameObject you can set the `Creation` bool to true, so you can create this object at the start of the game and then persist the object though out your game.